# Some pages of my Nuxt static website are not showing on firebase host

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, nuxt.js

so I deployed a Nuxt static site on Firebase host and it works fine for all pages.

this structure of the website is below

```
home
-products
--product1
--product2
--product3
--product4
-contact
-about
```

The problem is that when I load the refresh and load the website from any page other than the child pages of the products page, the website works. When I load the website from pages like domain/products/product1, the page doesn't load properly and I get this error.

eb5c34800a034e37286f.js:2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

which looks like the page data doesn't load.

The website works fine locally (npm run dev)

Opening the products pages directly from the ./dist folder give me a different error below.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

However, the website loads properly using the serve modules -->

```
serve ./dist
```

This makes me think the problem might be related to Firebase and how I configured the firebase.json.

```
//firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help!!.

Latest Update.
I tried uploading my static website to a different host and it works perfectly on Netlify. Still can't find an explanation.